# Jenkins project version in Nexus Repository Manager Publisher plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus, nexus3

This is my current working setup:
[image: setup]

I want to automate these variables:
[image: automation]

Is there a way to automate the version number in this build step? E.g. extract it from the root pom.xml?

I already tried putting ${project.version} inside the version field, but that didn't work either. Which placeholder am I required to use here, as the field is a required value and cannot be left empty?

Comment: Why not using Maven directly? via `mvn clean deploy`?

Comment: @khmarbaise It's a public repository

Comment: What does that mean: `It's a public repository`? You would like to publish into a repository which can simply being done via Maven? No need for supplemental configuration in Jenkins.

Comment: @khmarbaise I would like to use nexus repository manager for managing my repos.  If I had to use `mvn clean deploy` I would need my admin password for nexus inside my publicly hosted `pom.xml` on github, and I dont want that.

Comment: You have to use the credentials in Jenkins via Credentials store...not in Git ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Could you tell me how your solution would work? What things I should add to my pom.xml? I already have my credentials inside jenkins stored for nexus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `${POM_VERSION}` instead of `1.0.0`

You can also use `${POM_GROUPID}` and `${POM_ARTIFACTID}` for the `group` and for the `id` of the project.